# Why does "margin-top: -15px" makes my pseudo-element align correctly vertically?

Tags: html, css

I'm really breaking my brain to try to understand why my pseudo-element is always aligned vertically, no matter what size I decide my button should be, and all because of the "margin-top: -15px", does anyone understand this and can explain why this happens? I'll put the code below.

```css
.test {
  color: transparent;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

.test:after {
  content: "New Text";
  display: block;
  color: black;
  margin-top: -15px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="test">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to know why it's vertically centered or why your `-15px` margin doesn't seem to be doing anything?

Comment: I want to know why it's always centered vertically, no matter what height I decide to give the button, even tho it has a margin-top: -15px, by the way, if I remove the -15px margin, it gets out of the vertical center, which is really weird to me

Comment: I updated my answer. Should make it more clear.

Comment: Btw, if that answers your question, you can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're forgetting that the "Submit" text is in that button too. You can see it if you set something like `color: red` on your `.test` element. Your margin-top is essentially shifting the "New Text" up to around where the "Submit" text is. If you just remove the "Submit" text from the button element, the "New Text" will be shifted up by -15px.

```css
.test {
  color: transparent;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

.test:after {
  content: "New Text";
  display: block;
  color: black;
  margin-top: -15px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="test"></button>
```

To give you an idea of how your two bits of text were interacting with each other in the code you gave in your question:

```css
.test {
  color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

.test:after {
  content: "New Text";
  display: block;
  color: black;
  margin-top: -15px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="test">Submit</button>
```

See how they appear over the top of each other? It's because the negative margin on "New Text" has brought it up to around where "Submit" is displayed.

If you're wondering more generally why text is aligned vertically and horizontally in a button, it's because that's its default style. You can change the horizontal alignment by doing something like `text-align: left` on the button. To align text to e.g. the top, you could do:

```css
.test {
  color: black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<button class="test">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Oh, I see, in fact it was already centered, I was trying to understand why it was centered if it had a margin-top: -15px, maybe it's because the height of the "Submit" text influences it I guess?

Comment: @MarcoAmorim Yeah, if you added `color: red` to your `.test` element, you'd see the "Submit" text and the "New Text" text, and how they interact with each other (they essentially appear over the top of each other because you've shifted the "New Text" up with the negative margin).

Comment: I think I understand now, thank you very much for your help, and sorry for the noob question :D

Comment: No need to apologize. Gotta start somewhere :)